# Passing PHP Array to AJAX (Success) Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to pass an array to my AJAX function within the success function of an AJAX call. This array is data from my database using a `global $wpdb;` because this is easy to use and I know how to. Is there a way to pass this array to the AJAX function? Or is there a way to just get the data in AJAX?

I got this in my script tag and it is working:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('#date-select').on('change',function(){

        var seldate= jQuery(this).val();


        if(seldate!=''){

            var seldateEdited = seldate.replace("T", " ");

            jQuery.ajax({

                type:'POST',

                url:'http://esr-berlin.de/wp-admin/admin.php?page=einteilung_erstellen',

                data:'var='+seldate,

                success:function(html){

                            var output = '<option value="">Wähle HSR1</option>';

                            jQuery.each(html.data, function(i,s){
                                var newOption = s;

                                output += '<option value="' + newOption + '">' + newOption + '</option>';
                            });

                            jQuery('#hsrPop').empty().append(output);


                     }

            }); 

        }

    });
});
```

**EDIT**

I forgot something important. For the array or especially for the sql query I need a variable that I have in javascript. So I basically need another AJAX Call, right? How would I do that?

Comment: where are you failing ?

Comment: I am failing at passing a php array to the ajax function. I also need to get the variable `seldate` in my php for the array before I can pass it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Your server side code(admin.php) something like:-

```
$result = array();

//your code here to fetch data dynamically

$result['status'] = True; //based on your conditions optional
$result['data'] = array(0=>"option1",1=>"option2",2=>"option3") ;
echo json_encode($result);
```

Hope this will help.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
        jQuery('#date-select').on('change',function()
        {
            var seldate= jQuery(this).val();
                if(seldate!='')
                {
                    var seldateEdited = seldate.replace("T", " ");
                    jQuery.ajax({
                                        type:'POST',
                                        dataType:'json',         //added to receive json format data
                                        url:'http://esr-berlin.de/wp-admin/admin.php?page=einteilung_erstellen',
                                        data:'var='+seldate,
                                        success:function(html)
                                        {     
                                         //here you can check if html.status is True/False .. optional
                                                var output = '<option value="">Wähle HSR1</option>';
                                                jQuery.each(html.data, function(i,s)
                                                {
                                                    var newOption = s;
                                                    output += '<option value="' + newOption + '">' + newOption + '</option>';
                                                });
                                                jQuery('#hsrPop').empty().append(output);
                                         }

                                }); 

                }

        });
});
```

Comment: Now it isn't even changing anything. I think the line `dataType: "json",` is where the error happens. If I delete this line everything is fine. Looks like it wont succeed anymore.

Comment: Do you maybe know how I can get an array of my wpdb into AJAX? It could be the easier solution than going: server->client->server->client. It would only be: server->client->client

Comment: have you tried console.log(html) on success function . what does it produce ?

Comment: It somehow wont get into the success method anymore

Comment: do you see ajax call in network tab and can you update admin.php code for clear idea of your server side code.

Comment: I think my problem is, that I am running this dirty inside the same file. I should seperate them into two different files, or? The ajax call gets the status 200 so it's fine, but It still wont get into the success function tho

Comment: With the 200 status can you see json encoded response in "response" sub tab in "network" tab

Comment: I am not sure, where exactly should I see this in the code?

Comment: When you click on your request in network tab you will see a details window on right hand side where you can find Headers,Preview,Response..etc tabs. goto Response.

Comment: Yeah I know. There I can see the code from my file that requested. But it's the same file. As I said before, my php, and html/css code is in the same file. I think that might be a problem

Comment: There you should bring only get json encoded data as in example I showed. Better have a dedicated file for Ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the array in the PHP file and return this. It will just return a string to your AJAX function

```
json_encode($array)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

You can then use to convert it into a Javascript array for processing

```
JSON.parse(json)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Thanks. I forgot something important. For the array or especially for the sql query I need a variable that I have in javascript. So I basically need another AJAX Call, right? How would I do that?

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: @kennethenglisch You can pass an array into the ajax file using JSON as well it's just done the other way around so in the Javascript create an array convert it to JSON with

JSON.stringify(array)

and in the PHP

json_decode(json)